# Proving that the coefficents of the inverse formal power series takes the form $b_{n} = \frac{-1}{a_{0}} (\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i} b_{n-i}). $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification, formal-power-series

Proving that the coefficents of the inverse formal power series takes the form $b_{n} =  \frac{-1}{a_{0}} (\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i} b_{n-i}). $ \

I found this proof online:

> [image]

But I guess it is incorrect because it did not use the order of the power series $ a = \sum_{n}a_{n}x^n,$ am I correct? If so, below is my trial for the solution, If not please tell me how the argument used is the same as order argument.

**My trial:**

I got $a = a_{0}( 1 + xb(x))$ then the inverse $\frac{1}{1+xb(x)} = \sum (-xb(x))^k$ but then what happen to the first non-zero term I do not know, I got a hint that it starts further and furthur away but I do not know why and how that will help me in my proof? could any one help me in clarifying my confusions please?

Comment: I don't understand why you think the given proof is incorrect.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe because for the power series we should speak about its order which is the smallest $n$ such that $a_{n} \neq 0.$ we usually know the power series terms from below not from above because it is infinite ..... in the solution he assumed that coefficients started to be zro at nth term

Comment: ok, but here the statement is not for power series, but for *formal* power series. Which means that we don't care about the fact that there is an infinity of terms, and we don't care about convergence or divergence.

Comment: We are not sure that there is a term after which the terms becomes zero in the formal power series@TheSilverDoe

Comment: And ? The question is not about power series, but formal power series. So I don't see what you talk about an order, which has no sense for *formal* power series. You don't need that the terms become zero after a certain rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series) we have the formula to multiply two series

$$f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } a_n x^n;\;g(x)=\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } b_m x^n$$
$f$ and $g$ are inverse if $(fg)(x)=I(x)$, identity
$$f(x)g(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } a_n x^n\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } b_m x^m=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } c_k x^k$$
where coefficients $c_k$ are computed as follows
$$c_k=\sum _{j=0}^{k } a_jb_{k-j}$$
In our problem we have the first coefficent $c_0=1$ and all $c_k=0$ for $k>0$.

Thus $a_0b_0=1\to b_0=\frac{1}{a_0}$

$$c_1=a_0b_1+a_1b_0= 0\to b_1=-\frac{1}{a_0}\left(\frac{a_1}{a_0}\right)$$
Coefficient $n$-th is zero, so we have, if we know the previous $(n-1)$ coefficients
$$a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+\ldots+a_{n-1}b_1+a_nb_0=0$$
$$b_n=-\frac{1}{a_0}\left(a_1b_{n-1}+\ldots+a_{n-1}b_1+a_nb_0\right)$$
and finally
$$b_n=-\frac{1}{a_0} \sum_i^n a_ib_{n-i}$$

Hope it is useful

Comment: How are we sure that coefficient n-th is zero?

Comment: @Confusion because the resulting function $fg$ is the identity and its series expansion has coefficients $c_0=1,c_1=c_2=c_3=\ldots=0$